# derivative of a function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $ L:\mathbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ be the function $L(x)=\langle x,y\rangle$ , where $\langle,\rangle$ denotes some inner product on $\Bbb R^n$ and y is a fixed vector in $\Bbb R^n$. Further denote by DL, the derivative of L. Then which of the following are necessarily correct?

1. $ DL(u)= DL(v)$ for all $u, v \in \Bbb R^n$
2. $DL(0,0,...,0)= L$
3. $DL(1,1,...,1)= 0$

if we proceed using usual inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ then we can see that option $(1)$ is correct, but I cannot understand option $(2)$ and option $(3)$.

Comment: Is $DL(u)$ the derivative $\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}$ evaluated in $x=u$? If it is, then 2) and 3) are false.

Answer (score 2):

A function $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ is differentiable at a point $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$ if and only if there exists a *linear* function $A : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ satisfying $$\frac{f(x) - f(x_0) - A(x-x_0)}{||x-x_0||} \to 0$$ as $x \to x_0$.  The linear transformation $A$ is called the derivative of $f$ at $x_0$ and is denoted by $$A = Df(x_0).$$

Note that $A$, if it exists, is clearly unique. If $f$ is itself linear then $f(x) - f(x_0) - f(x - x_0) = 0$ so that $Df(x_0) = f$ for every $x_0 \in \mathbb R^n$.

The function you provide $Lx = \langle x,y \rangle$ is a linear function from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$, so that $DL(u) = L$ for every $u \in \mathbb R^n$.

This makes 1 and 2 true, and 3 is conditionally true if and only if $y = 0$.

Comment: If $f$ is linear $f(x)-f(x_0)-f(x-x_0)=0$ but how does that imply $Df(x_0)=f$ for every $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$? How does linearity help get this?